# SOQL query on multi object

Tags: soql, childrelationship

I'm trying to build a query on workbench to get the Name and Stage of opportunities created this quarter when there is task created by rep A or rep B on that account or on any of the contacts associated with that account. Ideally I also want to see the Task Type and Subject.

I have tried it several different ways but always come across a path error. Here is the most recent try:

```
SELECT Name,
   (SELECT Name, Type, LeadSource, StageName, CreatedDate, Device_Total__c
   FROM Opportunities
   WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_QUARTER),
   (SELECT Subject, Type 
   FROM Task
   WHERE CreatedById IN ('005b0000006bY2e', '005b00000065zB0') FROM Account
```

Comment: Kindly share what you had tried so far? Otherwise your question would most likely be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new here! I edited to add my latest failed attempt @RahulSharma . Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with this data? You may be able to get what you need with an anonymous script.

Comment: Adrain is right with Anonymous, note that Task object does not support joins in SOQL.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson , it is to monitor the success of telemarketing reps in passing over hot leads, I need to send this report to our VP of Marketing. I was trying to achieve this using a joint report, but it shows all opportunities created this quarter, regardless of having a task created by the reps A and B.  I guess you can still see what you want, but it's not very neat, so I was looking for a better solution. He is very savvy, so I was going to give him the SOQL query to run whenever he wants to see the results. But turns out I can't get there :(

Comment: You could whip up a `Visualforce Page` which displays only the correct data. You could also write a scheduled job to send this data as a CSV. You have a few options, depending on how much time you want to invest in this project.

Comment: Woah that would be impressive. I never created a Visualforce page, but maybe now is the time to give it a go. Thanks for the help! @AdrianLarson